# He can only cast the first index of my combobox but other datas cannot cast anymore only the first index

Tags: c#, mysql

Why my combobox didn't cast anymore when I choose the other indexes. He's work lately but when I rebuild my vs17 he gets bug.

How can I fix this? I don't know what's going on.

First:
[image: First]

Second:
[image: Second]

Last:
[image: Last]

```
    public void fillposition()
    {
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dr;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from position", con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string data = dr.GetString("EmpPosition");
            comboBox3.Items.Add(data);

        }
        con.Close();

    }
    public void getposition()
    {
        if (Int32.TryParse(comboBox3.SelectedIndex.ToString(), out tc))
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader dr;
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from position where EmpPosition=@EmpPosition ", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpPosition", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = tc;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                textBox1.Text = dr["Prefix"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getposition();
    }
    private void AddEmployee_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fillposition();
    }
```

I don't know what happen he's totally work lately but he cannot cast anymore when I rebuild the program

Comment: MySqlDataReader dr;
        int tc = 0;

Comment: fixed Inline images; spelling; grammar.

Comment: `SelectedIndex` is already an int, why convert to string and parse back?